# Bookmarked conversations don't show the (see full text) link on big posts

Tags: bug, chat, chat-bookmarks

Multiline posts in chat can stretch beyond the regular message size limits, and get quite long. Very long messages get cut off past a certain point and have the remainder of their content hidden, and have a (see full text) button added at the end which shows the whole long message when clicked. This button shows up while you're in a chat channel, [or in the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32841491#32841491).

However, the (see full text) button doesn't show up in a bookmarked conversation. The post just gets cut off, with no indication there's more to see. This means people can miss out on critical information in the conversation. [You can see an example of that here.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/chat-bug-example-for-meta-se-q-286268)

Could the (see full text) link be fixed to show up in bookmarked conversations too?